# Docker error: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'

Tags: node.js, docker, package.json

I'm trying to run a node image inside docker but I have this error:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
npm WARN !invalid#2 No description
npm WARN !invalid#2 No repository field.
npm WARN !invalid#2 No README data
npm WARN !invalid#2 No license field.
```

Here is my docker file. I want to put all my project files in /home/app/ folder in the container:

```
# Use an official node runtime as a parent image
FROM node:10

# Set the working directory to /home/app
#WORKDIR /home/app/

# Bundle app source
COPY . /home/app/

# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production
RUN npm install

# Make port 8000 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8000

CMD npm run dev
```

I'm on windows and I use hyper-V. My package.json is at the same level as my Dockerfile.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: For others running into this problem, make sure you're not overwriting the directory with a docker-compose volume

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When `npm install` command is run, the working directory is probably `/`, and there is no `package.json` here.

Just uncomment your line `WORKDIR /home/app/` in your `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 1):

My silly mistake was that I had forgotten to specify my `WORKDIR` before attempting to run my npm commands... Hope this helps someone too!
Be sure to make sure your `WORKDIR` is accurate for the `CMD` line...

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely an issue with the directory path. In the Dockerfile, you can try COPY . ./ instead of whatever you are having.
Since you already specified the working directory to be /home/app in the WORKDIR. Any subsequent docker commands will be executed inside that working directory.
Therefore, COPY . ./ will copy all the files/folders into current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

As you had set the WORKDIR to `/home/app/`, all the subsequent instructions will be executed in the same WORKDIR i.e. working directory. In your case it is `/home/app/`

So the `copy . /home/app/` instruction would copy your files to `/home/app/home/app/` directory.

Hence the `npm install` is unable to find the package.json.

Two solutions:

1. Either remove the WORKDIR instruction
2. Or Change the copy instruction to `COPY . .`